# How to activate javascript on materialize-css framework

Tags: javascript, materialize

I used this to activate it as mentioned in this website http://materializecss.com/navbar.html

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function(){})
</script>
```

there is no error in the console but I still didn't have the sidebar appearing.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like explain at the bottom of the mentionned documentation page, you have to add this :

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you So Much, It is Working Now with this

Answer (score 0):

Your code has nothing to do with the specified css framework. You have only created an event handler which calls a function, (function(){}) which does nothing, when the document is loaded (when the document is ready). Please share more of your code so we can help you.